# How to Display Multiple Google Maps in the page with API V3

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google map API v3, and i have an issue.

I get my coordinates from data base and i need to display them with more than one map, and i don't know the number of maps.

Here the code php code:

```
<div id="view-content">
            <?php foreach ($this->tag as $tag) : ?>

                <div id="list">
                    <div id="left">
                        <div id="map_canvas" style=" margin-left: 5px; width: 136px; height: 136px;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right">
                        <div id="listtitre">
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('action' => 'maptag', 'controller' => 'maptag', 'module' => 'agent', 'idtag' => $tag['idtag'])); ?>"> 
                                <?php echo $tag['name']; ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tagdisctitle">
                            <font>Address: </font><br/>
                            <font>Latitude: </font><br/>
                            <font>Longitude: </font><br/>
                        </div>
                        <div id="taglistdisc">
                            <?php
                            if (strlen($tag["address"]) > 52)
                                echo substr($tag["address"], 0, 52) . "...";
                            else
                                echo substr($tag["address"], 0, 52) . ".";
                            ?> <br/>
                            <?php echo $tag['latitude']; ?><br/>
                            <?php echo $tag['longitude']; ?><br/>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
```

The JS code:

```
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.6464862, 9.9565553 ),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });

    var marker;
    function placeMarker(location) {
        if(marker){ //on vérifie si le marqueur existe
            marker.setPosition(location); //on change sa position
        }else{
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //on créé le marqueur
                position: location, 
                map: map,
                icon : "/images/mapgo.png"
            });
        }
        latitude.value=location.lat();
        longitude.value=location.lng();
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

IDs must be unique on the page. Since you are outputting your HTML in a loop you are creating duplicate IDs, including the map_canvas div. You need to modify both your HTML and javascript so that a unique ID is created on each iteration. The simplest way to do this would be to keep a running counter that you increment on each iteration, and then include this counter in the ID:

```
<div id="map_canvas<?=$counter?>"> [...] </div>
```

you'll then need to change your JS to use this as well.

Comment: He could also use classes: `<div class="map-canvas"></div>`

Comment: I think Google Maps needs an ID. But yes ideally you'd put a class and an id on the div, and use the class to pull out all the map divs to then initialise with JS.

Comment: what about js, what i need to change?

Comment: Where you have `document.getElementById("map_canvas")` - map_canvas there needs to be changed to match your new ID, and you will need to run that code multiple times to initialise each map.

Comment: it didn't work, this what i have done:

`<div id="left">
                        <script>
                            function initialize(ltd,lgd) {
                            [...]
google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas<?php $i ?>"),
                                myOptions);
[...]
                        </script>
                        <?php echo "<body onload='initialize(".$tag['latitude'].",".$tag['longitude'].")'>"; ?>
                        <div id="map_canvas<?php $i ?>" style=" width: 136px; height: 136px;"></div>
                    </div>`

Comment: `<?php $i ?>` should be `<?php echo $i ?>`. View source of the resulting HTML page to ensure it is being output correctly.

Comment: same problem, just 1 map are displaying.

Comment: Check for javascript errors on the page. Otherwise can you give us the URL so we can see it?

Comment: You can download it from here: 
http://www.mediafire.com/?n5bqr7bahnetjbc

thanks a lot man :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545161/google-map-api-v3-issue/10558899#10558899